# Why is the absolute path of a drive letter equal to the working directory?

Tags: python, path, relative-path

I'm experiencing very strange behavior with python's `os.path` module. The drive letter of the working directory is treated as a relative path to the working directory itself. For example:

### Using `os.path.abspath`

`os.path.abspath('.')` prints `'C:\\Users\\myuser'`

`os.path.abspath('C:')` also prints `'C:\\Users\\myuser'`

### Using `os.path.join`

`os.path.join('.','Users','myuser')` gives the expected `'.\\Users\\myuser'`

Notice `'\\'` is inserted between all three entries. However:

`os.path.join('C:','Users','myuser')` gives `'C:Users\\myuser'`

Notice the lack of `'\\'` being inserted between `C:` and `Users`

### Using `os.path.abspath` with `os.path.join`

Despite the lack of `'\\'`, python accepts `'C:Users'` and treats it as `'.\\Users'` as seen here:

`'os.path.abspath(os.path.join('C:','Users','myuser'))` gives `'C:\\Users\\J34688\\Users\\myuser'`

which is the same as
`'os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.','Users','myuser'))` gives `'C:\\Users\\J34688\\Users\\myuser'`

### Using a different drive letter

This unexpected behavior is *not* seen when using other drives. For example:

`os.path.abspath(os.path.join('D:','Users','myuser'))` gives
`'D:\\Users\\myuser'`

Which to me seems far more reasonable.

### Conclusion

So what's going on here? Why is `'C:'` treated as `'.\\'`?

### Additional Notes

- I found a workaround to force the expected behavior by using `'C:\\'`, which will be treated as the actual letter drive. Still, in every other situation, the `'\\'` is optional (e.g. `'.'` is equivalent to `'.\\'`, and `'D:'` is equivalent to `'D:\\'`).
- This 'feature' holds regardless of what your current working directory is. If you `cd` to another directory within the `C:` drive, then `'C:'` will refer to that new directory just as `'.'` does. Furthermore, if you change to a different drive (say, `D:`), then `'C:'` will function as expected and the new letter will be take on this behavior (e.g. `'D:'` is now equivalent to `'.'`).

Comment: I think that's just how Windows processes relative pathnames, I don't think this is specific to Python.

Comment: Try `pathlib`. There are platform-specific `Path` objects to manipulate paths.

Comment: @Barmar By golly you're right... using 'cd C:Documents' in cmd prompt will be the same as 'cd .\\Documents'. MS never ceases to amaze me...

Comment: Still though... why doesn't os.path.join include the '\\' like it does in every other case?

Comment: `os.path.join()` doesn't return an absolute path if you give it relative paths.

Comment: @Barmar, that's not what I mean. If you do `os.path.join('.','Documents')`, it will return `'.\\Documents'` (even though '.' is relative, it still inserts the '\\')

Comment: In other words, it would be far more consistent for `os.path.join('C:','Documents')` to return `'C:\\Documents'`

Comment: How else is it supposed to join the `.` and `Documents` directories without putting a `\ ` delimiter between them.

Comment: But `C:` is not a directory, it doesn't need a delimiter between it and the directory.

Comment: "How else is it supposed to..." again, you're completely missing the point. I have no issue with "putting a \ delimiter between them." In fact, that's the expected behavior. What's *not* expected is *not* putting a \ delimiter between `C:` and a directory.

You say `C:` is not a directory, but then what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.abspath` calls [`GetFullPathName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea) in the Windows API. The documentation for that states that

> If you specify "U:" the path returned is the current directory on the "U:" drive

This is just how Windows handles paths, not related to Python.

The documentation for [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) also states

> Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

Comment: Thanks! The API call to `GetFullPathName` makes a lot of sense. I never knew Windows treated `C:Path` as `.\\Path`. I have to admit though, the `os.path.join` documentation goes right over my head, but I'm sure smarter folks than me have good reasons for the implementation! I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: In something cross-platform like Python there can be a fine line to walk between doing what a specific OS's users might expect (e.g. the behaviour you see here) and doing something different that can be made consistent across platforms (e.g. treating it as 'C:\whatever'). As the behaviour around drive letters must necessarily be Windows-specific anyway, they probably felt it made sense to go with the behaviour provided by the underlying platform and not try to modify it, which can get quite complex.